# Adding background color in apex:inputCheckbox

Tags: visualforce, checkbox

I am trying to change the default background color in the checkbox. I can't able to figure out what CSS I should use. I am trying the below code but it is not working.

```html
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opportunities" tabstyle="opportunity">
    <apex:form id="changePrivacyForm">
        <style>
            input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" var="o">
                <apex:column value="{!o.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.account.name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Private?">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.isprivate}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is incorrect for checkbox background color

You need:

```
<style type="text/css">
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
            accent-color: yellow;
        }
</style>
```

[Reference](https://web.dev/accent-color/)

Before checking:

[image]

After checking:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Cropredy! It is working absolutely the same as I expected.

Comment: @rupalsingh I'm glad this works.  As a service to the Community, posters should mark the answer as accepted (the check mark).